# Add a test runner to playwright in docker

Tags: java, junit, playwright

I am starting using playwright, I have pulled the docker image and I am wondering how should I run tests. I have followed some old messages in playwright slack and run this command :

```
 docker run -d -it --rm -v /C/Workspace/playwrite/src/test/java/org/example/TestExample.java:. --ipc host --shm-size 2gb mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/java:v1.14.0-focal
```

The container has started, the test has been moved in docker but I don't think it has been run. My question is does the docker playwright has already a test runner such as junit? If nor do I have to modify the docker image? I don't find any docs that explain that.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is to run the Playwright image, which then provides you with  an environment to setup and run Playwright

```
# run in the root of your Playwright project
docker run -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.16.2-focal /bin/bash

# you are now inside the container (bash)
root@f4cfe077964d:/e2e# npm install
root@f4cfe077964d:/e2e# npx playwright install
root@f4cfe077964d:/e2e# npx playwright test
```

More details about using the Playwright Docker image [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/e2e-testing-with-playwright-and-docker-91dd7eb11793)